# Japan pocket wifi that uses NTT Docomo

Tags: japan, internet, wifi, phone-networks

Are there any pocket wifi options that use NTT Docomo as the cellular provider?

We will be travelling to a rural part of the Wakayama Prefecture and, based on our research, NTT Docomo has the best performance in countryside regions.

Comment: Are you looking to hire a unit, or simply purchase a prepaid SIM card? Also, what airport are you flying in to?  Prepaid data SIM cards for all networks are widely available at the airports from vending machines and airport vendors.  A 7 day 1GB card is JPY 3,000.

Comment: @PassKit Out of curiosity, what are some prepaid SIMs using the au network?

Comment: @PassKit We're looking to hire a unit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[eConnect](https://www.econnectjapan.com/products/wifi/)** is one company that I used when I was in Japan that I know has that, and they use NTT Docomo network. (it's specified under [network](https://www.econnectjapan.com/products/sim/1gb) if you go to the prepaid SIM page). I went to very isolated areas in Hokkaidō and it worked fine

[image: network]

Comment: Thanks, I also see that their [300k WiFi-ToGo product](https://www.econnectjapan.com/products/wifi/300k) uses NTT DoCoMo. The faster 3G and 4G pocket WiFi products use Y!mobile so we'll have to see whether or not we can manage with 300k.